# AdSense Matched Content Ad Unit Console Errors

Tags: ads, adsense

I am diagnosing an issue I am seeing with what appears to be a Matched Content AdSense ad unit on our site.

I am seeing this error in the Chrome devtools console

(NOTE: Specific ad ids filled with fake values for now)

```
abg_lite.js:1 Uncaught Error: bad conv util ctor args
    at new zc (abg_lite.js:1)
    at Bc (abg_lite.js:1)
    at new Ac (abg_lite.js:1)
    at new Jc (abg_lite.js:1)
    at Kc (abg_lite.js:1)
    at new Ic (abg_lite.js:1)
    at Qc (abg_lite.js:1)
    at ads?client=ca-pub-adsIdNumber&a-bunch-of-other-probably-unimportant-url-params-here
```

Here is the ad slot code.

```
<ins class="adsbygoogle" 
        style="display:block" 
        data-ad-format="autorelaxed" 
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-adClientId” 
        data-ad-slot=“adSlotId”></ins> 
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({}); </script>
```

I can't seem to find much documentation on why this might be causing errors, and attempting to browse the source linked by the error did not tell me much more than "if A throw Error".

(The function looks like this if people are curious)

```
function zc(a, b, c) {
    if (!a || !b) throw Error('bad conv util ctor args');
    this.h = a;
    this.g = c
  };
```

'a' in this function appears  to be "https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/conversion/?a-bunch-of-url-params"

but 'b' appears to be undefined/blank string, which is why the Error is thrown.

Has anyone experienced this error before?

Or at a glance, is there something you're seeing from what I've posted above that looks wrong?